# Conversion from string to Date in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The question is reframed by giving more details.

I have a dataframe "dailyshow" Schema is:

```
scala> dailyshow.printSchema
root
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- occupation: string (nullable = true)
 |-- showdate: string (nullable = true)
 |-- group: string (nullable = true)
 |-- guest: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample Data is:

```
scala> dailyshow.show(5)
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
|year|        occupation| showdate| group|           guest|
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
|1999|             actor|1/11/1999|Acting|  Michael J. Fox|
|1999|          Comedian|1/12/1999|Comedy| Sandra Bernhard|
|1999|television actress|1/13/1999|Acting|   Tracey Ullman|
|1999|      film actress|1/14/1999|Acting|Gillian Anderson|
|1999|             actor|1/18/1999|Acting|David Alan Grier|
+----+------------------+---------+------+----------------+
```

Below code is used to transform and generate results which return the top 5 occupations between the time period "01/11/1999" and "06/11/1999"

```
scala> dailyshow.
    withColumn("showdate",to_date(unix_timestamp(col("showdate"),"MM/dd/yyyy").
    cast("timestamp"))).
    where((col("showdate") >= "1999-01-11") and (col("showdate") <= "1999-06-11")).
    groupBy(col("occupation")).agg(count("*").alias("count")).
    orderBy(desc("count")).
    limit(5).show
        +------------------+-----+                                                      
        |        occupation|count|
        +------------------+-----+
        |             actor|   29|
        |           actress|   20|
        |          comedian|    4|
        |television actress|    3|
        | stand-up comedian|    2|
        +------------------+-----+
```

**My question is how to code and get the same result when using RDD?**

```
scala> dailyshow.first
res12: org.apache.spark.sql.Row = [1999,actor,1/11/1999,Acting,Michael J. Fox]
```

I used `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string to date in a `DataFrame`.

Below is the code:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")

dailyshow.
  map(x => x.mkString(",")).
  map(x => x.split(",")).
  map(x => format.parse(x(2))).first // returns Mon Jan 11 00:00:00 PST 1999
```

Comment: What does `dailyshow` contain? And your first two maps look like they cancel each other.

Comment: @philantrovert       dailyshow is a dataframe. 
Contents are [year: int, occupation: string, showdate: string, group: string, guest: string]
The first 2 maps are for converting the DF to RDD as the DF begins with "[" and ends with "]". To avoid extracting these 2 characters, the first 2 maps are used.

Comment: Sample data in `datashow` and expected output will be of great help to answerers. Please add if you can, thanks.

Comment: I had reframed the question. Kindly help

Comment: So basically whatever yow showcased here using dataframes, you want to accomplish that usinf RDDs?

Comment: So just so I understand. You want to repeat the process above in RDD instead of dataframe? May I ask why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a lot of deprecation warning while writing this :D

So we have this data in a RDD

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(
     Array("1999","actor","1/11/1999","Acting","  Michael J. Fox"),
     Array("1999","Comedian","1/12/1999","Comedy"," Sandra Bernhard"),
     Array("1999","television actress","1/13/1999","Acting","Tracey Ullman"),
     Array("1999","film actress","1/14/1999","Acting","Gillian Anderson"),
     Array("1999","actor","1/18/1999","Acting","David Alan Grier")))
```

Then as per your question, we do a filter on date:

```
val filtered = rdd.filter{ x => 
    format.parse(x(2)).after( new java.util.Date("01/10/1999")) && 
    format.parse(x(2)).before(new java.util.Date("01/14/1999")) 
}
```

Then we get this :

```
Array[Array[String]] = Array(
Array(1999, actor, 1/11/1999, Acting, "  Michael J. Fox"), 
Array(1999, Comedian, 1/12/1999, Comedy, " Sandra Bernhard"), 
Array(1999, television actress, 1/13/1999, Acting, Tracey Ullman))
```

Then we group them with the second element as the key and count the number of occurrences :

```
filtered.keyBy(x => x(1) ).map((_, 1) ).reduceByKey(_+_).map{ case ((a, b) ,c) => (a,c) }
```

If everything goes right , you should get :

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((television actress,1), (Comedian,1), (actor,1))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked... However i modified the code for grouping. Used the following one. `filtered.map(x => (x(1),1)).reduceByKey(_+_).take(5)`

Comment: Oh great. That's better and less complex.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would use spark's internal date functions as defined in org.apache.spark.sql.functions instead of manually doing it myself with simple date and mapping. This is because using dataframe functions is much simpler, much more idiomatic, less error prone and performs much better.

Lets assume you have a dataframe df which has column called dateString which contains a date string in the format MM/dd/yyyy.

Let's also assume you want to convert it to a date in order to extract the year and then display it in the format yyyy.MMMMM.dd

What you can do is:

```
val dfWithDate = df.withColumn("date", to_date($"dateString")
val dfWithYear = dfWithDate.withColumn("year", year($"date"))
val dfWithOutput = dfWithYear.withColumn("dateOutput", date_format("$date", "yyyy.MMMMM.dd")
```

Now the year column would contain the year and the dateOutput column would contain the string representation with your format.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am working on a RDD. These functions don't work on RDD

Comment: @Jayson You begin with dataframe and convert it to RDD. Why do need to do so directly in the beginning? If you provide a more thorough example of what you want (i.e. some input example of the original dataframe and how you plan to use the result) then it would be possible to improve

Comment: I had reframed the question. Kindly help